# Get Transition history information of a Jira ticket in json format

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

Hi I can get the json for all the transitions for a jira ticket by `/rest/api/2/issueid/transitions`, but it is not giving me the information as who has made that transition. I need the person's name who has made those transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `transitions` end-point provides information about available transitions for the issue for the user. Not the transition history.

If you want to know who made which transition, you have to query issue's changelog via common `issue` end-point and expanding changelog.

See more details about the `expand` parameter in the documentation:
https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/latest/#api/2/issue-getIssue.

Example:

```
https://jira.domain.com/rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE-1234?expand=changelog
```

You can also limit the size of the response by adding `&fields=""` (no fields/customfields are returned in the response, only the changelog).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more thing can we get this information for multiple issues in one go.

Comment: Yes, it's possible but you have to use the [`search` REST API endpoint](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/latest/#api/2/search-search) to retrieve multiple issues at once. Again, you have to use `expand=changelog` param and you can limit the size of the response using by using `fields=""` param. *Example*: `https://jira.domain.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project%3DMYPROJ%20AND%20issuetype%3DBug&fields=""&expand=changelog`

Comment: Hi thanks, this is working in browser. But I need to read that data in python. I have jql as a string 'jql=issue in (abc-123,abc-124)' and passing the complete link to session.get but getting an empty list. PLease help.

Comment: In Python you process JSON data as any JSON data. If you have problems processing JSON data in Python, search for a solution or submit a new question here on SO. Btw, in Python, you can also use [Jira API package](https://pypi.org/project/jira/) to process data from Jira in more convenient way.